# const char* concatenation

Tags: c++, c, string-concatenation

I need to concatenate two const chars like these:

```
const char *one = "Hello ";
const char *two = "World";
```

How might I go about doing that?

I am passed these `char*`s from a third-party library with a C interface so I can't simply use `std::string` instead.

Comment: I'm confused - the original questioner wrote "c++" tag - then someone else removed it. What's the state of affairs for this question? Is C++ code allowed?

Comment: @Johannes: That's a better question xD.

Comment: Also note the original question did NOT refer to C - I've removed that tag.

Comment: I switched the C++ tag to C because the OP accepted an answer that uses arrays on stack and `strcpy` and `strcat` calls, I thought that made sense to change the tags.

Comment: Added C *and* C++ tags. As the OP explains in a comment, he's writing C++ code, but calling a library which uses a C interface. The question is relevant in both languages.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

In your example *one* and *two* are char pointers, pointing to char constants. You cannot change the char constants pointed to by these pointers. So anything like:

```
strcat(one,two); // append string two to string one.
```

will not work. Instead you should have a separate variable(char array) to hold the result. Something like this:

```
char result[100];   // array to hold the result.

strcpy(result,one); // copy string one into the result.
strcat(result,two); // append string two to the result.
```

Comment: Ha! I had used strcpy, and strcat and it didn't work but that was the one way I didn't try it, thanks!

Comment: what about char* result; result = calloc(strlen(one)+strlen(two)+1, sizeof(char)); and THEN the strcpy+strcat?

Comment: @luiscubal: Yes that would work too...just use a (char*) cast, as calloc returns void*

Comment: The problem with this answer is the hard coded array size.  That's a really bad habit to get into, especially if you don't know what size "one" and "two" are.

Comment: In the first example, `strcpy(one,two);` should be `strcat(one,two);` (not that *that* makes it correct, as you correctly point out).

Comment: what about `sprintf(dest,"%s%s",one,two)` and forget the copy?

Comment: luiscubal's solution is better in allocation :)

Comment: @luiscubal your answer should be accepted, giving a random size to a char array is not the way, is a terrible code

Answer (score 97):

The C way:

```
char buf[100];
strcpy(buf, one);
strcat(buf, two);
```

The C++ way:

```
std::string buf(one);
buf.append(two);
```

The compile-time way:

```
#define one "hello "
#define two "world"
#define concat(first, second) first second

const char* buf = concat(one, two);
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the "compile-time" way only works when `one` and `two` are both string literals.

Answer (score 34):

If you are using C++, why don't you use `std::string` instead of C-style strings?

```
std::string one="Hello";
std::string two="World";

std::string three= one+two;
```

If you need to pass this string to a C-function, simply pass `three.c_str()`

Comment: Because I am using a library that was coded in C so the functions return const char *

Comment: @AnthoniCaldwell : Thanks for the laugh. I could not because of work pressure.:D

Comment: @AnthoniCaldwell every C++ developers common nightmare: having to work with C libraries and their const char *s...

Answer (score 27):

Using `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

std::string result = std::string(one) + std::string(two);
```

Comment: The second explicit constructor call is not necessary

Answer (score 22):

```
const char *one = "Hello ";
const char *two = "World";

string total( string(one) + two );

// to use the concatenation as const char*, use:
total.c_str()
```

**Updated:** changed 
    `string total = string(one) + string(two);`
to `string total( string(one) + two );` for performance reasons (avoids construction of string two and temporary string total)

```
// string total(move(move(string(one)) + two));  // even faster?
```

Comment: @iburidu have you measured it? What about situations where safety trumps performance? (They are common situations)

Comment: @Sqeaky There are absolutely no situations where this is safer than any other solution, but it is ALWAYS slower than a compile time solution, by invoking runtime behavior as well as almost certainly invoking memory allocation.

Answer (score 10):

One more example:

```
// calculate the required buffer size (also accounting for the null terminator):
int bufferSize = strlen(one) + strlen(two) + 1;

// allocate enough memory for the concatenated string:
char* concatString = new char[ bufferSize ];

// copy strings one and two over to the new buffer:
strcpy( concatString, one );
strcat( concatString, two );

...

// delete buffer:
delete[] concatString;
```

But unless you specifically don't want or can't use the C++ standard library, using `std::string` is probably safer.

Comment: If the OP can't use C++, he can't use `new`.  And if he can use it, he should use `std::string`, as you say.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you have to create some dynamic memory space.  Then you can just strcat the two strings into it.  Or you can use the c++ "string" class.  The old-school C way:

```
  char* catString = malloc(strlen(one)+strlen(two)+1);
  strcpy(catString, one);
  strcat(catString, two);
  // use the string then delete it when you're done.
  free(catString);
```

New C++ way

```
  std::string three(one);
  three += two;
```

Comment: why do you need dynamic memory?

Comment: -1 for me, first with the C-way you need to use malloc and free. Then even if you do new then it should be delete[] and not delete.

Comment: The library I am using is coded in C not C++ so all of the functions return const char * not string.

Comment: @Naveen, the tag said "C++".  If you can't use new and delete, then he shouldn't have used the C++ tag.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you're using C++ with a C library and therefore you need to work with `const char *`.

I suggest wrapping those `const char *` into `std::string`:

```
const char *a = "hello "; 
const char *b = "world"; 
std::string c = a; 
std::string d = b; 
cout << c + d;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know the size of the strings, you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    const char* q1 = "First String";
    const char* q2 = " Second String";

    char * qq = (char*) malloc((strlen(q1)+ strlen(q2))*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(qq,q1);
    strcat(qq,q2);

    printf("%s\n",qq);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strstream`. It's formally deprecated, but it's still a great tool if you need to work with C strings, i think.

```
char result[100]; // max size 100
std::ostrstream s(result, sizeof result - 1);

s << one << two << std::ends;
result[99] = '\0';
```

This will write `one` and then `two` into the stream, and append a terminating `\0` using `std::ends`. In case both strings could end up writing exactly `99` characters - so no space would be left writing `\0` - we write one manually at the last position.

Comment: Deprecation shouldn't matter too much. Even if it's removed from a future version of the standard, it's not so much work to re-implement in your own namespace.

Comment: @Steve, indeed :) And writing your own `streambuf` directing output to a char buffer used with `ostream` isn't too difficult either.

Answer (score 3):

```
const char* one = "one";
const char* two = "two";
char result[40];
sprintf(result, "%s%s", one, two);
```

Answer (score 0):

Connecting two constant char pointer without using strcpy command in the dynamic allocation of memory:

```
const char* one = "Hello ";
const char* two = "World!";

char* three = new char[strlen(one) + strlen(two) + 1] {'\0'};

strcat_s(three, strlen(one) + 1, one);
strcat_s(three, strlen(one) + strlen(two) + 1, two);

cout << three << endl;

delete[] three;
three = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a C-style trick for achieving the (const/constexpr) string literals concatenation in build time. It should not matter because `const char*` are actually C-style stuff anyhow. And without dynamic allocations, strlen, and all the ugly stuff posted here. Everything is done by the compiler, nothing during execution.

The trick is to use the preprecessor `#define` directive.

```cpp
#define PREFIX "/dev/"
#define DEVICE PREFIX "pts/3"

constexpr const char* defaultDevice = DEVICE;
```

This should assign `/dev/pts/3` to the variable (without any blank between the 2 preprocessor macros).