# C++ overloading + operator in order to always concatenate strings of every kind

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

It's very pointless and troublesome that everytime that you need to concatenate two strings it is necessary to do at least:

```
std::string mystr = std::string("Hello") + " World";
```

I would like to overload operator+ and use it in order to always do a concat between tho char* in this way:

```
std::string mystr = "Ciao " + "Mondo".
```

How would you do? I'd like to find a best practice. Thank you...

Ah does boost have something to solve this?

Comment: You know, one question mark is sufficient in order to indicate that something is a question. Using six of them in a row does not make it any more of a question. Unless your cat sat on the keyboard, there's no reason for it.

Comment: STL string concatenation best practices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611263/efficient-string-concatenation-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot make `+` work like this. To define an operator overload, at least one of the operands must be a user-defined type.

However, the functionality is built in: if you just put two string literals together `"like" "this"`, they will automatically be joined together at compile time.

Comment: @Andry: Why would you want to type `"Hello" + "World"` when `"Hello" "World"` (a) is shorter to type and (b) works?

Comment: @Andry that's just what I finished saying in the first part. Notice, in the second part, that there is no `+` in `"like" "this"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There is no way to overload operators between built-in types.
I'm also not sure why it's so "troublesome". If you do a lot of string operations, then surely one or both parameters will **already** be of type `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Think about it - what is "Ciao " and "Mondo", really?  They are static arrays of characters.  You can't add static arrays together, as the compiler will helpfully point out for the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string mystr = "Ciao " + "Mondo";
  std::cout << mystr << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

(output:

```
In function 'int main()':
Line 5: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [6]' and 'const char [6]' to binary 'operator+'
```

That's it.  This is pretty much a dupe of: [const char* concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995053/const-char-concatenation).