# C++ multi strings in char

Tags: c++, char

i have problem with multi strings in 1 char

```
//------------------------------------------------
char* P1P2P3 = { FirstName,LastName,Email };
    if (strcmp(buffer5, P1P2P3) == 0)
          {
           //OK
          }
    else
          {
           //Not OK
          }
//----------------------------------------------
```

this is my problem :

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'char *'
```

i want it come like this

First Name+Last Name+Email

for ex :

First name : Max

Last name : TEST

Email : Max@gmail.com

it should come like this :
MaxTESTMax@Gmail.com

Thanks guys

Comment: Did you mean to write `char* P1P2P3[] = ...`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm afraid your question needs some more information to be able to receive answers: what exactly are FirstName, LastName and Email? Are they char* variables? If so, would you like to concatenate them? In that case [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995053/const-char-concatenation) might help you. But either way, try to provide a little more context. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The only valid initialization for C-style strings is:

```
const char* const P1P2P3 = "literal string";
```

All other ways of making such strings can't be done by initializing.

A C-style strings way in C++ would be

```
char* P1P2P3 = new char[ENOUGH];
sprintf(P1P2P3, "%s%s%s", FirstName, LastName, Email);
//...
delete[] P1P2P3;
```

With C++ strings:

```
std::string P1P2P3 = std::string(FirstName) + LastName + Email;
if (buffer5 == P1P2P3) //...
```

Comment: _"The only valid initialization for C-style strings is:"_ What about `const char* const P1P2P3 = FirstName LastName Email;`?

Comment: @molbdnilo I supposed that, unfortunately OP doesn't tell what these are.

Comment: Which version of C has `new` and `delete` ?

Comment: @Shreevardhan: I reworded a bit.

Answer (score 0):

option 1: use `std::string` instead of `char*`

```
std::string FirstName,LastName,Email;
 ...
std::string P1P2P3 = FirstName+LastName+Email;
```

option 2: use `std::stringstream`

```
std::stringstream sout;
sout<<FirstName<<LastName<<Email;
char* P1P2P3 = sout.str().c_str();
```

option 3: use `sprintf` to print string into buffer

option 4: use `strcat` to append 2 string, then again to append the 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go with C++ way of doing it.

```
std::string P1P2P3 = FirstName + LastName + Email;
if (P1P2P3 == buffer5) {
    // OK
}
else {
    // Not OK
}
```